# Call a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I am new to `node.js` .Here I write a sample function in node.js to print the contents of a `json` file as follows.

```
exports.getData =function(callback) {
readJSONFile("Conf.json", function (err, json) {
  if(err) { throw err; }
  console.log(json);

    });
console.log("Server running on the port 9090");
```

What I am doing here is I just want to read a `json` file and print the contents in console. But I do not know how to call the `getData` function. While running this code it only prints the `sever running on the port..", not my`json` contents.

I know the above code is not correct

How can I call a function in `node.js` and print the `json` contents?

Comment: You defined a function but you don't have a statement to call it. Add   getData(null);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js is just regular javascript. First off, it seems like you are missing a `}`. Since it makes the question easier to understand, I will assume that your `console.log("Server...` is outside `exports.getData`.

You would just call your function like any other:

```
...
console.log("Server running on the port 9090");
exports.getData();
```

I would note that you have a `callback` argument in your getData function but you are not calling it. Perhaps it is meant to be called like so:

```
exports.getData = function(callback) {
    readJSONFile("Conf.json", function (err, json) {
        if(err) { throw err; }
        callback(json);
    });
}
console.log("Server running on the port 9090");
exports.getData(function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

Truthfully, your getData function is a little redundant without any more content to it since it does nothing more than just wrap `readJSONFile`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't take this the wrong way, but your code appears to be a mixed up mess of unrelated examples. I recommend you start by learning the basics of JavaScript and node.js (for example, read [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) and [Felix's Node.js Beginners Guide](http://nodeguide.com/beginner.html)).

---

But on to your code. First of all, you are creating a function (called `getData`) and exporting it. Then you're printing "Server running on the port 9090". There is no server code in your script, and the function you created is never executed.

I think this is what you intended to write:

```
readJSONFile("Conf.json", function (err, json) {
    if(err) { throw err; }
    console.log(json);
});
```

Assuming that `readJSONFile` is a real function.